# AWS Cognito with federated social provider(Google,Facebook,Apple) android java

Tags: java, android, amazon-cognito, social-networking

How to insert the Credentials (Token, E- mail ID) fetched from Social media Login account in AWS Cognito Database?

Tried using following code

```
 AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {
                    Log.i("INIT", String.valueOf(userStateDetails.getUserState()));
                    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().federatedSignIn(IdentityProvider.GOOGLE.toString(), account.getIdToken(), new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(final UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {
                            //Handle the result
                            Log.i(TAG, "mobileClient Google login result: " + userStateDetails.getUserState().toString());
                         //   AWSCredentials credentials = mobileClient.getCredentials();
                           // Log.i(TAG, "mobileClient Google login, posting credentials event..."+credentials.getAWSSecretKey());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "sign-in error", e);
                        }
                    });
```

Expectation : Need to insert data in AWS Cognito user pool